# securityd goes nuts every 4 minutes & 30 seconds

Tags: security, console

securityd spams my console with the following :

```
19/04/2012 16:23:17.405 com.apple.securityd: Value of bTransmit: 00000001
```

repeated 563 times (after disabling the default mps_limit of 500).

4 minutes and 30 seconds later (give or take a couple of seconds), it does it all over again.  Oddly, the message is split over that boundary :

```
04/05/2012 09:32:16.092 com.apple.securityd: Value of bTransmit: 00000001
04/05/2012 09:32:16.092 com.apple.securityd: Value of bTransmit: 00000001
04/05/2012 09:32:16.092 com.apple.securityd: Value 
04/05/2012 09:36:19.470 com.apple.securityd: of bTransmit: 00000001
04/05/2012 09:36:19.470 com.apple.securityd: Value of bTransmit: 00000001
04/05/2012 09:36:19.470 com.apple.securityd: Value of bTransmit: 00000001
```

It's pretty annoying.  Anyone know what causes it, or what bTransmit might be?  There seems to be no mention of it on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a smartcard reader or some other kind of security related hardware?  Seems like this is an error in a kernel extension or driver for some piece of security hardware.

Comment: hmm.  I do have a USB VPN key, but I don't recall it having any custom drivers.  I do have some tuntap software installed... I'll take a look when I'm back at work next week and see if either of those might be the culprits.

Comment: Prompted by your comment I ended up grepping my entire harddrive for 'bTransmit'.  Turns out, it's from the SafeNet SDK, which is used for my eToken doohickey.  So... yeah.  I'll go complain to them and see what they have to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are facing a continuous flow of information messages.
This flow is truncated by chunck of 500, which is the default value of
`mps_limit` in `/etc/asl.conf`. This means that your flow of security related messages is at a rate **> 500 / s**. This is huge.

Could you open:

```
/var/log/secure.log
/var/log/kernel.log
```

and check which message could be related with this continuous
flow of information messages?

Could you type the following command (in an `xterm` or `Terminal` window):

```
top -o msgsent
```

to check if the culprit could be a local process and tracked down through its huge level of messages sent? You will have to enlarge
your window to more than 152 characters large to see the film.

Comment: There's nothing related in secure.log or kernel.log, unfortunately ("IOSurface: buffer allocation size is zero" every few minutes, but I'm assuming that's nothing to do with it).  Nothing jumps out at me in 'top', but the msgsent values are all pretty high so it's difficult to see the wood for the trees...  I've updated the initial post with a couple more details